# Qt nested model views

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am coming from C# and WPF, and there we have quite nice way of binding collections to views, populating data via current DataContext.

I have been learning Qt and I know that there is a way of providing a view with a model (QAbstractItemModel) and then by modifying the model you can update the view automatically, which is nice and what I want.

My current issue is that I want to create a editor view for the following class `Definition`

```
class Definition
{
public:
    vector<Step*> Steps;

    bool SomeBoolMember1;
    bool SomeBoolMember2;
    int SomeIntMember1;
    int SomeIntMember2;
}
```

`Step` is

```
class Step
{
public:
    vector<Requirement*> Requirements;

    bool SomeBoolMember1;
    bool SomeBoolMember2;
    int SomeIntMember1;
    int SomeIntMember2;
}
```

And `Requirement` is

```
class Requirement
{
public:
    RequirementType Type;
}
```

My aim is to build a view to be able to modify a collection of `Definition`s. A possible view could be something like this:

[image]

When a different Definition is selected the selected item view is updated (to load data of selected Definition), and then we have a scrollview with a list of steps. Each step with a list of requirements.

As you see it is not rocket science but I know it might be tedious. Any hints of how to structure models/view models to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: Just a remark: the "Remove step" button should be shown in each step and "Remove req" - next to each requirement.

Comment: Yeah it could be, it could also remove the last (or selected) step/requirement.

Comment: I see. Another question. Do you insist on using a model/view?

Comment: Well I don't really care, if it does the job done, but I believe this is kind of situation that is most useful. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Let me prepare an example, to show you what I have in mind.

Comment: Preparing the example I realised I was wrong and the idea I've had would not work. Anyway, I will try this with a model/view, but it will take some time.

Comment: [Qt model-view](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) is a very generic framework (but not super easy to understand in my opinion). One important point is you don't directly maps your own data-classes to the view, you **never** do in Qt-ModelView : *"I want to display a list of Step instances"*. Everything goes through the *item roles*, so you display/edit a list/table/tree of basic values only (the value is of course to be built based on your Step instance but is in the end just a string or an int etc...).

Answer (score 6):

Your question is quite broad. Qt's models are very general and there are many ways to structure them to achieve the same behavior. I've created a simplified example how you can structure them. I only used `Definition` and `Step`, adding `Requirement` to `Step` is analogical to adding `Step` to `Definition`...

```
struct Step
{
    bool SomeBoolMember1 {false};
    int SomeIntMember1 {0};
};

struct Definition
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Step>> Steps;

    bool SomeBoolMember1 {false};
    int SomeIntMember1 {0};
};

struct Data
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Definition>> definitions;
};
```

Models are quite straightforward, I've created one model for `Definition` and one for `Step`. Each model has columns that represent properties of these objects and rows of the models represent one instance of the object. Model for `Definition` has a column for `Step`, that returns model for `Step` for given `Definition`.

```
class StepModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    using BaseClass = QAbstractItemModel;

public:
    enum Columns
    {
        E_BOOL_1,
        E_INT_1,
        E_REQUIREMENT,
        _END
    };

    StepModel(Definition* definition, QObject* parent) :
        BaseClass(parent),
        definition(definition)
    {
    }

    virtual QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return createIndex(row, column, nullptr);
    }
    virtual QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const override
    {
        return QModelIndex();
    }
    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return definition->Steps.size();
    }
    virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return _END;
    }
    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override
    {
        if (role != Qt::DisplayRole) return QVariant();

        const auto& step = definition->Steps.at(index.row());
        switch (index.column())
        {
            case E_BOOL_1:
                return step->SomeBoolMember1;
            case E_INT_1:
                return step->SomeIntMember1;
            case E_REQUIREMENT:
                return QVariant();
        }
    }
    virtual bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole) override
    {
        if (role != Qt::EditRole) return false;

        auto& step = definition->Steps.at(index.row());
        switch (index.column())
        {
            case E_BOOL_1:
                step->SomeBoolMember1 = value.toBool();
                return true;
            case E_INT_1:
                step->SomeIntMember1 = value.toInt();
                return true;
            case E_REQUIREMENT:
                assert(false);
                return false;
        }
    }
    virtual bool insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) override
    {
        assert(count == 1);
        beginInsertRows(parent, row, row);
        definition->Steps.push_back(std::make_shared<Step>());
        endInsertRows();
        return true;
    }
    virtual bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) override
    {
        assert(count == 1);
        beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row);
        definition->Steps.erase(definition->Steps.begin() + row);
        endRemoveRows();
        return true;
    }

private:
    Definition* definition;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(StepModel*)


class DefinitionModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    using BaseClass = QAbstractItemModel;

public:
    enum Columns
    {
        E_NAME,
        E_BOOL_1,
        E_INT_1,
        E_STEPS,
        _END
    };

    DefinitionModel(QObject* parent) :
        BaseClass(parent)
    {
    }

    virtual QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return createIndex(row, column, nullptr);
    }
    virtual QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const override
    {
        return QModelIndex();
    }
    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return definitionData.definitions.size();
    }
    virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return _END;
    }
    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override
    {
        if (role != Qt::DisplayRole) return QVariant();

        const auto& definition = definitionData.definitions.at(index.row());
        switch (index.column())
        {
            case E_NAME:
                return QString("Definition %1").arg(index.row() + 1);
            case E_BOOL_1:
                return definition->SomeBoolMember1;
            case E_INT_1:
                return definition->SomeIntMember1;
            case E_STEPS:
                return QVariant::fromValue(new StepModel(definition.get(), nullptr));
        }
    }
    virtual bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole) override
    {
        if (role != Qt::EditRole) return false;

        auto& definition = definitionData.definitions.at(index.row());
        switch (index.column())
        {
            case E_BOOL_1:
                definition->SomeBoolMember1 = value.toBool();
                return true;
            case E_INT_1:
                definition->SomeIntMember1 = value.toInt();
                return true;
            default:
                assert(false);
                return false;
        }
    }
    virtual bool insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) override
    {
        assert(count == 1);
        beginInsertRows(parent, row, row);
        definitionData.definitions.push_back(std::make_shared<Definition>());
        endInsertRows();
        return true;
    }
    virtual bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) override
    {
        assert(count == 1);
        beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row);
        definitionData.definitions.pop_back();
        endRemoveRows();
        return true;
    }

private:
    Data definitionData;
};
```

In this example, `DefinitionModel` owns instance of `Data`, which is not something you would wanna do in real application, it's just for the sake of simplicity.

Dialog is a little bit more complicated as you have to dynamically create widgets for `Steps` as you create new instances. I've created a simple mapping for widgets, that are mapped to columns of it's appropriate model. Each time you select new Definition, you load the data back from the model by this mapping.

```
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0)  :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        auto definitionModel = new DefinitionModel(this);
        ui->definitionView->setModel(definitionModel);

        connect(ui->definitionView->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::currentRowChanged, this, [=]
        {
            update();
        }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

        connect(ui->addDefinition, &QPushButton::pressed, this, [this]
        {
            auto* model = ui->definitionView->model();
            model->insertRow(model->rowCount());

            ui->definitionView->update();
            ui->definitionView->setCurrentIndex(model->index(model->rowCount() - 1, 0));
        });
        connect(ui->removeDefinition, &QPushButton::pressed, this, [this]
        {
            auto* model = ui->definitionView->model();
            if (model->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                const int row = model->rowCount() - 1;
                for (const auto& widget : steps[row])
                {
                    unmap(widget);
                }
                steps.erase(steps.find(row));
                model->removeRow(row);
            }
        });

        auto getCurrentDefinition = [this] { return ui->definitionView->currentIndex().row(); };
        map(ui->definitionInt, definitionModel, DefinitionModel::E_INT_1, getCurrentDefinition);
        map(ui->definitionBool, definitionModel, DefinitionModel::E_BOOL_1, getCurrentDefinition);

        connect(ui->addStep, &QPushButton::pressed, this, [=]
        {
            if (getCurrentDefinition() == -1) return;
            auto widget = new QWidget(this);
            auto layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
            auto checkBox = new QCheckBox(widget);
            layout->addWidget(checkBox);
            auto spinBox = new QSpinBox(widget);
            layout->addWidget(spinBox);
            auto removeButton = new QPushButton(widget);
            removeButton->setText("remove");
            layout->addWidget(removeButton);
            ui->rightLayout->addWidget(widget);

            const int currentDefinition = getCurrentDefinition();
            steps[currentDefinition].push_back(widget);

            auto model = definitionModel->data(definitionModel->index(currentDefinition, DefinitionModel::E_STEPS), Qt::DisplayRole).value<QAbstractItemModel*>();
            model->setParent(widget);
            const int rowCount = model->rowCount();
            model->insertRow(rowCount);

            auto getRow = [=]
            {
                auto it = std::find(steps[currentDefinition].begin(), steps[currentDefinition].end(), widget);
                return std::distance(steps[currentDefinition].begin(), it);
            };
            map(checkBox, model, StepModel::E_BOOL_1, getRow);
            map(spinBox, model, StepModel::E_INT_1, getRow);

            connect(ui->definitionView->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::currentRowChanged, widget, [=] (const QModelIndex& current)
            {
                widget->setVisible(current.row() == currentDefinition);
            });

            connect(removeButton, &QPushButton::pressed, widget, [=]
            {
                model->removeRow(rowCount);
                unmap(checkBox);
                unmap(spinBox);
                ui->rightLayout->removeWidget(widget);
                auto it = std::find(steps[getCurrentDefinition()].begin(), steps[getCurrentDefinition()].end(), widget);
                steps[currentDefinition].erase(it);
                delete widget;
            });

            update();
        });
    }

    ~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }

private:

    void map(QCheckBox* checkBox, QAbstractItemModel* model, int column, std::function<int()> getRow)
    {
        connect(checkBox, &QCheckBox::toggled, this, [=] (bool value)
        {
            model->setData(model->index(getRow(), column), value, Qt::EditRole);
        });

        auto update = [=]
        {
            checkBox->setChecked(model->data(model->index(getRow(), column), Qt::DisplayRole).toBool());
        };

        mapping.emplace(checkBox, update);
    }

    void map(QSpinBox* spinBox, QAbstractItemModel* model, int column, std::function<int()> getRow)
    {
        connect(spinBox, static_cast<void (QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged), this, [=] (int value)
        {
            model->setData(model->index(getRow(), column), value, Qt::EditRole);
        });

        auto update = [=]
        {
            spinBox->setValue(model->data(model->index(getRow(), column), Qt::DisplayRole).toInt());
        };

        mapping.emplace(spinBox, update);
    }

    void unmap(QWidget* widget)
    {
        mapping.erase(mapping.find(widget));
    }

    void update() const
    {
        for (const auto& pair : mapping)
        {
            pair.second();
        }
    }

    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    std::map<QWidget*, std::function<void()>> mapping;
    std::map<int, std::vector<QWidget*>> steps;
};
```

Ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout" stretch="1,2">
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>10</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QListView" name="definitionView">
        <property name="showDropIndicator" stdset="0">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="selectionBehavior">
         <enum>QAbstractItemView::SelectRows</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
        <property name="topMargin">
         <number>10</number>
        </property>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="addDefinition">
          <property name="text">
           <string>add</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="removeDefinition">
          <property name="text">
           <string>remove</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>10</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="rightLayout">
        <item>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
          <item>
           <widget class="QCheckBox" name="definitionBool">
            <property name="text">
             <string>CheckBox</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QSpinBox" name="definitionInt"/>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
        <item>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>10</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Steps</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="addStep">
            <property name="text">
             <string>add</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>20</width>
          <height>40</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```